# Ho to deploy angular app with ng build --aot?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng-build

I have a website created using angular in localhost everything works fine, in heroku also works fine, now I want to deploy the page to my server,

Here is repo : [agency repo](https://github.com/throne1986/agency)

I run the following command

```
ng build --aot
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error

```
ERROR in : Type NgStickyDirective in C:/custom-xammp/htdocs/agency/majeni/node_modules/ng-sticky/ng-sticky.d.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in C:/custom-xammp/htdocs/agency/majeni/src/app/app.module.ts and NgStickyModule in C:/custom-xammp/htdocs/agency/majeni/node_modules/ng-sticky/ng-sticky.d.ts! Please consider moving NgStickyDirective in C:/custom-xammp/htdocs/agency/majeni/node_modules/ng-sticky/ng-sticky.d.ts to a higher module that imports AppModule in C:/custom-xammp/htdocs/agency/majeni/src/app/app.module.ts and NgStickyModule in C:/custom-xammp/htdocs/agency/majeni/node_modules/ng-sticky/ng-sticky.d.ts. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes NgStickyDirective in C:/custom-xammp/htdocs/agency/majeni/node_modules/ng-sticky/ng-sticky.d.ts then import that NgModule in AppModule in C:/custom-xammp/htdocs/agency/majeni/src/app/app.module.ts and NgStickyModule in C:/custom-xammp/htdocs/agency/majeni/node_modules/ng-sticky/ng-sticky.d.ts.
```

What do I need to do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error is about a 3rd part directive being redeclared in your module AppModule.

Make sure that you don't have `NgStickyDirective` in your `AppModule`'s `declarations` . Just having `NgStickyModule` in your `imports` should be enough.

```
declarations: [/* only your own components and directives*/],
imports: [NgStickyModule, /* other modules*/ ]
```